# Twitter API, send image url ,ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

I'm using twitter gem for Twitter API in Rails.All works properly but I'm not able to send image url and link with my post to twitter site..
Here is my code:

In Model:-

```
 def twitter
   @twitter ||= Twitter::Client.new(oauth_token: token, oauth_token_secret: secret )
 end

def post_to_twitter(user)
  begin
    @twitter = user.authentications.find_by_provider('twitter')
    if @twitter.present?
      twitter = @twitter.twitter
      twitter.update(self.title)
    end
  rescue Exception => e
    Rails.logger.debug e.message
  end
end
```

In controller:-

```
def create      
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  @post.user_id = current_user.id
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save         
      @post.post_to_twitter current_user        
      format.js { render :layout => false }
  else        
    @message = "Please enter content"
    format.js { render :layout => false }
  end
end
```

end

By using: twitter.update(self.title)...The title of my app goes to twitter site but how can I Send any link and image url same as title??

Answer (score 0):

Make a regular **POST request** using AccessToken to post the links and urls- [oauth rdoc](http://oauth.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/OAuth/AccessToken.html).

Get the access token by [Using the oauth ruby gem](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples#ruby).

The all and all [process of Getting to grips with the Ruby OAuth gem and the Twitter API](http://michaelhallsmoore.com/blog/Getting-to-grips-with-the-Ruby-OAuth-gem-and-the-Twitter-API).

Comment: Thanks for your's answer Jain..one more question, how can I send url to twitter (like: localhost url),so that if I click on it, it'll redirect to my application

Comment: you don't have to send this redirect url explicitly. Instead you define the return url on your routes and the twitter api will recognize that which url of your application is needed to redirect to your application.

Comment: Get a quick idea of testing at local- read this- http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2009/08/17/how-to-quickly-set-up-a-test-for-twitter-oauth-authentication-from-your-local-machine/